# Kubernetes deployment freezes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When trying to run command:

```
kubectl get deployments
```

I get this message:

```
C:\Users\win 10\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\helloworld-gke>kubectl rollout status deployment helloworld-gke
Waiting for deployment "helloworld-gke" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
```

and nothing has happened since then, is this a freeze or it is taking time to deploy ?

Comment: Check if your new pods are crashing on startup or otherwise not Ready.

Comment: how to make them ready?, i am a beginner

Comment: @coderanger currently i have ready as 0/1 and available as 0.

Comment: describe the deployment

Comment: NAME                                               READY   STATUS                   RESTARTS   AGE
helloworld-gke                                  0/1          InvalidImageName   0                   74m

Comment: Please share the result of running `kubectl get deployments` as the message you posted is the result of running `kubectl rollout status deployment helloworld-gke`. What does `kubectl describe deployment <your_deployment_name>` say ? Can you see any details in `events` section ?

Answer (score 1):

You gave an invalid docker image name in your deployment so it can’t succeed.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstarts/deploying-a-language-specific-app#php     this is the link where i am trying to create kubernetes, any idea where i couldve givien it the invalid docker image?